# How to make accelerating collisions in andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

Making a simple pong game, I want the ball to accelerate in speed every time it hits a paddle instead of slowing down. How do I do this?

Comment: Depends: do you use physics? What did you tried already? Post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using andengine then you can do it by using
[AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension)